# How to handle timeout a method in java?

Tags: java, timeout, timeoutexception

I am calling a method in which there is loop which will end only if it find some results otherwise it keeps on looping until it find

```
public Collection<Serializable> searchItems(Collection<String> tags) {
    Collection<Serializable> answers = (Collection<Serializable>) 
        this.issueParallelOperation(tags, RemoteOperation.getIndex, 
        null, null, null, null, AggregationStrategy.joinCollection);
}
```

The code inside the method this.issueParallelOperation() keeps on looping until it find the result. I want to stop the operation after 1 min and set the **answers** value manually like null. I cant make changes inside this.issueParallelOperation() method as it is called by many other methods. Can anyone please suggest me some ideas how to solve this issue in this **searchItems()** method

Comment: Can you provide the definition for the issueParallelOperation method (or the code)? Usually the modern paradigm is to provide a method call that requests termination (rather than killing a thread).  You should also probaly invoke this call in a separate thread so you can make such a "stop" request.

Answer (score 0):

You can record the start time of the function, and then check the current time against the start time and your duration whenever you loop. Something like:

```
public Object functionWithTimeout(long duration){
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

   while(someCriteria){
      if(System.currentTimeMillis() - start > duration){
         //the function has timed out
         break;
      }

      //whatever code you want to repeat until the timeout
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Requires original method change.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that the OP couldn't change the original method. I'll leave the answer for now, for people who *can* change the original method.